# Multiple UIPageViewController's

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using a `UINavigationController` with a `UIPageViewController` (first pvc) as the root controller.
Inside this pvc instance i have multiple view's where i can scroll through. This is all working fine.

Then i select to push from one of these views, i drill down to a level with a second pvc. When i'm scrolling with the second pvc and reached the end of the sequence, i'm automatically continuing scrolling with the first `UIPageViewController`.

My question is how to disable the gesture and lock the scrolling for this first pvc on that moment of scrolling in the second pvc?

Here is the navigation controller stack

```
/////--UINavigationController

/////----------UIPageViewController (first instance of pvc)

/////---------------UITableViewController [ TV01 ] push here to second pvc

/////---------------UITableViewController [ TV02 ]

/////---------------UITableViewController [ TV03 ]

/////---------------------UIPageViewController (second instance of pvc)

/////---------------------------UIViewController 

/////---------------------------UIViewController

/////---------------------------UIViewController (is scrolling to TV02)
```

Comment: yusuf.yazilim@gmail.com send mail to me in turkish language. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for my question and i'd like to post my answer here. The main `UIPageViewController` uses some UIScrollView object to handle scrolling (at least for transitionStyle `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`). I've disabled the scrolling option for this UIPageViewController before i push a new `UIPageViewController`. So you have always one `UIPageViewController` active for swipe.

You can iterate by controller's subviews (pageViewController.view.subviews) to get it.

```
-(void)setScrollEnabled:(BOOL)enabled forPageViewController:(UIPageViewController*)pageViewController{
    for(UIView* view in pageViewController.view.subviews){
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
            UIScrollView* scrollView=(UIScrollView*)view;
            [scrollView setScrollEnabled:enabled];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```